# MySQL query based on highest value but column is VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql

Running into a bit of a problem here. We have a system where we track our website hostings and I'm developing a frontend portal on this already pre-existing system.

In the database, the table looks something like:

`id | company_id | renewal | domain_name`

and an example couple entries in a MySQL database:

```
 1 | 5 | June 2014 | www.example.com
 2 | 5 | June 2015 | www.example.com
 3 | 5 | June 2016 | www.example.com
 4 | 5 | June 2017 | www.example.com
 5 | 5 | June 2018 | www.example.com
 6 | 5 | June 2014 | www.stackoverflow.com
 7 | 5 | June 2015 | www.stackoverflow.com
 8 | 5 | June 2016 | www.stackoverflow.com
 9 | 5 | June 2017 | www.stackoverflow.com
10 | 5 | June 2018 | www.stackoverflow.com
```

I am wanting to `SELECT *` where the `company_id = 5` - that's no problem. I then want to show all domains where the `renewal` is the highest - basically I want to return:

```
 5 | 5 | June 2018 | www.example.com
10 | 5 | June 2018 | www.stackoverflow.com
```

Getting unique domains is simple, I've achieved that by `GROUP BY(domain_name)`, but am clueless on sorting by `renewal`, especially because it isn't a simple `int`, rather a combination.

Comment: So your column type is VARCHAR?  Do the entries all look the same your are they mixed (i.e. June 2018, jun. 2013, JUNE 2001, June '09...).  How homogeneous is the text?  Is it always June?

Comment: Entries all look the same, for example June 2010, August 2010, September 2015, etc. They're all the full month names plus the full year. Not always June

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend to convert this table to something with a real date in it, so you can sort it. For the time being, you could use MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function, which tries to parse the date according to a given format.

Here that would be:

```
SELECT domain_name, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(renewal_date, '%M %Y')) AS max_renewal_date
FROM table
WHERE company_id = 5
GROUP BY domain_name
```

Comment: Makes sense - this is outputting the lowest one though, i.e. "June 2014" whereas "June 2018" is wanted.

Comment: What's the query you're using? The above would always return a date (2018-06-00) or NULL, it would never return a string like "June 2014".

Comment: Apologies, worded incorrectly and confused myself. It's outputting NULL currently.

Comment: Okay. Figured it out! Turns out `STR_TO_DATE` wants a _day_ aswell, so I ended up doing something like `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(renewal_date, " 01"), "%M %Y %d")` and just not taking into consideration the day in my code. Many thanks for the help!